# Emulate an external monitor using VNC

Tags: windows, multi-monitor

I am looking for a program that can emulate an external monitor using VNC. I.e. the program would add a virtual display that can be accessible through VNC: clients connecting to the VNC would only see this display, not the actual/physical displays. I don't mind about the price. The VNC server should run on Windows.

Use case: I have 2 laptops, one running on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, the other one running on OS X 10.10. I would like to use the OS X laptop as an external monitor for the Windows laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exacly what you are looking for but it may help:

[synergy: move your mouse from one computer to another](https://symless.com/synergy/)

It's a VNC-based application that will allow you to use the keyboard and mouse of your "main" computer to control the current session of your secondary PC.

If you were using linux or Windows server on your main PC, you could run an extra remote session on the secondary PC and it would be almost the same as a second monitor (except that you would not be able to move applications from one "monitor" to another).

**Edit:**

There used to be a commercial application called MaxiVista that did exactly what you want, over the network, but it seems they went out of business.

If you feel adventurous, these guys says they are implementing something similar, it's in beta state, and it's free for non-commercial use:

http://spacedesk.ph

Comment: Looks like MaxiVista was rebranded as ShareMouse but is now similar to synergy, the one you suggested.