# How to show PowerPoint presentation while seeing the notes on other computer?

Tags: windows, presentation, powerpoint

I am showing the presentation from a computer connected to a projector.

I want to see the notes on an other computer. I want that when I change the slide, I will see the next slide's notes on the other computer.

Do you have any idea how should I do that?

I am searching for a software that can help me solve this problem.

Comment: You could *extend* the screen (Win+P -> extend) and then on the projecter (extended screen), have the slideshow, and on the normal computer monitor, have the notes, but it won't auto-change the notes I think

Comment: I cannot extend the screen, because it is on two machines. The project is far, and connected to other PC.

Comment: Ahh, sorry - I missed that when I read the question :/ Is there any price requirement? Free/paid (budget?)

Comment: You could still use the extended desktop, if you combine it with a remote desktop solution from the projector computer. :-)

Comment: No price requirements. As i know Extend desktop not work until you connect second screen.

Comment: FYI: [Emulate an external monitor using VNC](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19870/903)

Answer (score 2):

Besed on @Franck.

What I am doing is 1: Faking an external monitor. Don't need any software for that (https://superuser.com/a/796884/185370).

Then I present the presentation. One one monitor the presentation, and on the second (fake) montior the notes.

I am connect to the computer with any remote desktop software (realvnc, ultravnc, teamviewer, etc'), then I am choose to show only the second (fake) monitor with the notes.