# Multimonitor VNC/Remote Desktop

Tags: gratis, remote-access, multi-monitor, remote-desktop

Here is the setup I'd like to achieve:

Upstairs is my home office, with my work computer with 3 monitors.
Downstairs is my server rack, with my laptop (no extra monitors).

My laptop has Windows 10 Home, so I don't have access to RDP, or I would just use that.

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to remote into my laptop from my desktop, and span the session over all three monitors, thus creating two virtual monitors.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Real VNC (free edition v. 5.2.3)
- FullScreen: True
- FullScreenChangeResolution: True
- UseAllMonitors: True

  These settings give me the following result:
- Left monitor: Black
- Center monitor: Laptop screen
- Right monitor: Black

I'm open to free remote software, or free software to create virtual monitors.

Comment: If everything on RealVNC is "true", why doesn't it solve your requirements?

Comment: I'm not a VNC expert, but I assume it doesn't solve my requirements because RealVNC isn't creating virtual monitors on the laptop.  The Laptop only has the one display.  I'll attach a screenshot.

Comment: @Thomas, I was going to leave a screenshot, but the PrintScreen button goes to the laptop and takes a picture of just the laptop screen, but I've added a descriptive text of what I see.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this question was down-voted?

Comment: FYI: [Emulate an external monitor using VNC](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19870/903)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up upgrading to Windows 10 Pro so I can just use RDP.